# post_max_size does not change

Tags: php, post, max, size, version

I changed `post_max_size` in the `php.ini` file and then restarted my webserver with

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

However when I try to import a db file then I get the error `(Max: 2,048KiB)`

Also `localhost/info.php`shows my modified `post_max_size`. But when I import the db file then it stills show the 2MB error.

I changed php7.3 to php7.1 with this command

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
```

I think problem was created when I switched php versions.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: You also have to change the upload_max_filesize value

Comment: try with `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `upload_max_size` and `post_max_size`to `128mb`.

For further information take a look at the [php configuration directives for file upload](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads)

Answer (score 1):

You need to also change `upload_max_filesize`. If it is set to a smaller value, then it will limit the effect of `post_max_size`